# How do i load index.html in webview from android http server

Tags: android

if i enter http server url in client side app it have to load the url in webview along with index.html with css,js which is stored in http server assets folder, how can i do this anyone please help me to complete my android app

Answer (score 0):

Add permission on your AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And add this code in you MainActivity.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```